# CSS in the html tags, text not staying in box

Tags: html, css

I'm sending emails within my PHP application. I know it's not recommended but to keep things simple I just want to put the CSS style in the tags. I've tried this:

```
<div style=\"width: 500px; height: 600px; background-color: green;\">
<h1>Title</h1>

<div style=\"width: 460px; height: 540px; background-color: white; margin-top: 10px; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;\">
$content
</div>
</div>
```

The styling works fine but the $content string is quite long and the text just flows out of the box instead of neatly going to the next line. Is this something particular when you use the style attribute in tags? Or does it have to do with the way email clients read the email out?

Is there a way I can fix this without using an external CSS file?

EDIT: Here is my problem in a screenshot:

[image]

This is with `word-break: normal`. I would like to avoid breaking the words but keep the $content within the boundaries of the div.

Is this a problem with formatting emails? The exact same code in a regular html pages displays itself within the boundaries of the div.

Comment: Why do you have a limit on the height?

Comment: why are you escaping the double quotes? It may be helpful to show the **entire** code if you are escaping because those lines are inside a PHP function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To keep content in my container, this usually does it for me:

```
.break-word {
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

As much as possible, though, I would suggest an external CSS file.

Comment: It does work but by breaking the words. Can I not just force him to go to the line at the end of the div width, but with normal breaking points?

Comment: The `word-wrap` property accepts `break-word` (allows unbreakable words to be broken) and `normal` (breaks words only at allowed break points).

Comment: I've set it to normal aswell (that is the default if a value is not specified no?) But you can see the results in the screenshot I added above. Breaking the words on an email just really doesn't look right. I don't understand why the text doesn't stay within the boundaries of the div in the first place.

Comment: Normal is in fact the default value. If the text goes outside the box, I would sacrifice design and make sure its readable and use `break-word`. Or, from your screenshot, would it be possible to force a line break with a `<br />` or a new paragraph?

Comment: Technically I could force a line break but the messages will be of different length and are generated on the go so it won't be practical. I don't undersantd, is this a problem with formatting html emails? Because the exact same code on a regular html page displays itself within the boundaries of the div.

Comment: As mentionned by @Scott, you are escaping your double quotes, maybe this is a result from that. Have you tried without escaping the double quotes? If this does not do it, try using an external stylesheet (for development purposes as email styles are preferably inline). See if this helps

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37456/discussion-between-publi-design-and-user2018084)

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
    <div style="width: 500px; height: 600px; background-color: green;">
    <h1>Title</h1>

    <div style="width: 460px; height: 540px; background-color: white; margin-top: 10px;     margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; word-wrap:break-word;">
$content
    </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: I added `word-wrap: break-word` on the second `<div>`. Nevertheless, just return the backlashes if it's for PHP. My bad :)

Answer (score -1):

```
.break-word {
   padding:1em 1em;
}
```

Comment: While this may answer the question it's better to add some description on how this answer may help to solve the issue. Please read [_How do I write a good answer_](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) to know more.